# Ajax doesn't work on the Opera browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, opera

I am using jQuery AJAX on my application and latest version of Opera does not display any AJAX what so ever. Works on all other browsers.

In HEAD:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have been wrapping my head around this and cannot come up with a solution. I do not get any page errors. Is there someone more intelligent than me that can guide me to a solution?

Here is an example code:

```
<fb:serverFbml width = "600px">
<script type="text/fbml">
  <fb:fbml>
      <fb:request-form
                action="<?=$conf['dir']['app_url'];?>test.php"
                method="POST"
                target="_top"
                invite="false"
                type="NAME"
                content="TEST <fb:req-choice url='<?=$conf['dir']['app_url'].'test.php?inviter='.$fbme['id']?>' label='TEST' />"
                >

                <fb:multi-friend-selector
                showborder="false" 
                cols="4" 
                actiontext="TEST">
                </fb:multi-friend-selector>
    </fb:request-form>
  </fb:fbml>
</script>
</fb:serverFbml>
```

Comment: jQuery **does** work in Opera, it must be specific to your code. Post your ajax calls so we can test them out.

Comment: well it is a facebook application. what that is even more strange is that not even the facebook invite ajax form loads. Meaning that there is nothing in particular wrong with the ajax calls themselves. The only thing I can think of is that there is something on the page itself that is strambled, but im not getting any errors!

Comment: <fb:serverFbml width = "600px">
<script type="text/fbml">
<fb:fbml>
<fb:request-form
action="<?=$conf['dir']['app_url'];?>test.php"
method="POST"
target="_top"
invite="false"
type="NAME"
content="TEST <fb:req-choice url='<?=$conf['dir']['app_url'].'test.php?inviter='.$fbme['id']?>' label='TEST' />"
>
<fb:multi-friend-selector
showborder="false" 

                    cols="4" 

                    actiontext="TEST">

                    </fb:multi-friend-selector>

        </fb:request-form>

      </fb:fbml>

    </script>

  </fb:serverFbml>

Comment: That is the code I use for the invite system...

Comment: @Peter Johansson: You can edit your original post!

Comment: I think this is invalid XML. Does not look [well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml#Well-formedness_and_error-handling).

Comment: hmm, its the standard one that facebook advices you to use.

Comment: @elusive those fb: prefixes are called namespaces and part of XML standard.

Comment: @c0rnh0li0: I know what namespaces are. They _are_ valid. What bothers me is the value of the `content`-attribute of `fb:request-form`. It contains other XML elements. What is that supposed to do? It needs to be escaped to validate.

Comment: @elusive Ah sorry. Overseen that, thats indeed not well formed. OP should fix it before trying other things.

Answer (score 0):

Opera is stricter with cross domain javascript communication. A workaround for it is to use a local proxy of the js file.

create a channel file called channel.html with this content:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/us_US/all.js"></script>
```

Put this file into a publicly accessible folder and add it to the channelUrl configuration:

```
FB.init({ appId: myFBAppId, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, channelUrl: "http://xxx.net/channel.html" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work in the newly released Opera 11 beta version? We have at least one fix that affects Facebook Connect there (it is however in browser.js so it will only work if http://www.opera.com/docs/browserjs/ shows that browser.js is active and recently updated).